# Limit two jobs to run in parrallel in apscheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

Is there a way which i can use to limit the two jobs to run in parallel in apscheduler? Basically i don't want the two jobs to be running at the same time. Is this supported by apscheduler natively ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to 1 max worker :

```
executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
}
```

And apply it to your Scheduler, example for `BackgroundScheduler`:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)
```

source: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html#configuring-the-scheduler

Comment: how will this make sure that when one job is running the other job is not gonna run ?

Comment: oh well you have to set the max_worker to 1 if you dont want them to run in parallel, updating answer